# Return value of child processes in fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am aware that the child process will return 0 while the parent process will return the PID value of the child process. However, if multiple fork() functions are called, what would the return value be for the child of the child process (or processes that are forked >= 2 times)? For example in:

```
int main()
{
   Fork();
   Fork();
   printf("hello\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

fork() is called twice, and hence the child process will also continue forking. Thus regarding this, will the forked out processes from the child process all return to 0? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered actually capturing the return value and printing it out? That would give a quick answer to your question.

Comment: Also, this is `C`, which is case-sensitive; `Fork` is not the same as `fork`.

Comment: If you call `fork()` in process P, it returns in P with the PID of the new child and in a new child process of P with 0. It doesn't matter how many parents P has, and it doesn't matter if you executed a new program in the meantime or just forked multiple times without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we rewrite this code a little, the output might be illuminating.

```
int main()
{
   int a, b;
   printf("pid=%d\n",getpid());
   a=fork();
   printf("pid=%d a-fork=%d\n",getpid(), a);
   b=fork();
   printf("pid=%d a-fork=%d b-fork=%d\n",getpid(), a, b);
   
}
```

When I ran it, output of this was:

```
pid=285
pid=285 a-fork=286
pid=286 a-fork=0
pid=285 a-fork=286 b-fork=287
pid=286 a-fork=0 b-fork=288
pid=287 a-fork=286 b-fork=0
pid=288 a-fork=0 b-fork=0
```

So, the parent process calls fork and creates process 286.
Then the parent process calls fork again, and creates process 287.

Meanwhile, process 286 calls fork and creates process 288

Graphically:

```
      a-fork  b-fork
285 -> 286,   287
       286 -> 288
```

Note that the order of these could vary a bit.
There's nothing to prevent the first child from forking before the parent completes the second fork.